# aggregate attributes for nodes of the same type with the same value

Tags: xslt, attributes, aggregate

I have this problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
    <container>
        <Facility count="1" normalied="Mauritius Branch Campus">Mauritius Branch Campus</Facility>
        <Facility count="1" relevance="0.2">Mauritius Branch Campus</Facility>
        <Country count="1" relevance="0.8">Mauritius</Country>
        <Country count="1" normalized="Mauritius">Mauritius</Country>   
    </container>
</root>
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
    <container>
        <Facility count="1" relevance="0.2" normalied="Mauritius Branch Campus">Mauritius Branch Campus</Facility>
        <Country count="1" relevance="0.8" normalized="Mauritius">Mauritius</Country>
    </container>
</root>
```

In the example e reported only elements like `<Facility>` and `<Country>` but the may be more, the same as the type of attributes.

Is there a way to achieve this via XSLT ?

Thanks in advance.

R

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? Do you only want to group all `Facility` with the same string contents together? What happens if two `Facility` have the same attribute (e.g. `Count="1"`, `Count="2"`) with different values, which value belongs into the result?

Comment: Hi Martin, you're right the count attribute may appear in multiple elements. For me it's nor relevant that value so I can set it as 1 or have the sum of the values across the multiple elements. It's the same for waht I have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 you can use `for-each-group`, the following code first groups by `node-name(.)` (assuming you only want to group all `Country` and all `Facility` together, but not elements of a different name) and then by string contents:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="container">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name(.)">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by=".">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/@*"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online demo at http://xsltransform.net/pPzifp3.